# Jquery datatable static row at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have been working with jQuery datatable some time now and it does allow for a lot of clever things but as of yet, i have not been able to figure this part out...

I have my datatable whice allows the columns to be sorted, but i need to have a static row at the top of the table, always. 
This row should not move when the table is being sorted.

I was unable to find method to anchor the row to the top of the table and the alternative, adding the row to the header after the table was built, have not been working either as the newly added row is removed as soon as i hit the sort possibilites (assuming the row is dies in the redrawn method)

So, does anyone have any ideas on how to archive a static row and the top of the datatable?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the datatable consists of multilple tables and i accidentially inserted my header into the wrong one.

Adding my row to the top most thead seems to do the trick